# How to fit four images in one complete xml layout

Tags: android

I want to make my image in given way .

AAAA     BBBBB  then in next line 
CCCC     DDDDD

I tried grid layout but dont know how to align them for every screen size .

Comment: Use LinearLayout with `android:orientation="horizontal"` attribute.

Comment: u mean that i must go for two linear layouts ? as i may need two linearlayouts as i have 4 images.

Comment: No. Just one linear layout with horizontal orientation. Start putting everything in it and everything will appear just as you want. Use weight if you want to make it fit screen in evenly distributed manner.

Comment: ok let me check it out . And anyways thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Master LinearLayout(it will be vertical). Inside it, use two LinearLayout(both horizontal). In master LinearLayout, use Layout_weight of 1.0. and in two child linearLayout, use layout_weight 0.5. 
Then put the images in each child linearLayout with layout_weight 0.5 again.

You might want to use Layout_gravity="right"&"left" to properly oriented it.